# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter in web.xml

Tags: struts2, web.xml

This is my web.xml Code,While running I am getting error like this..How to resolve this?

"**SEVERE: Exception starting filter Struts
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter**"

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
      <display-name>HelloStruts</display-name>


      <filter>
      <filter-name>Struts</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
      </filter>

      <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>Struts</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>

      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

Comment: The classpath requires Struts 2 core packages.

Comment: Which version of S2?

Answer (score 43):

if you are using struts2 version 2.5 you need to change from:

```
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
```

to:

```
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
```

[Version Notes 2.5](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Struts+2.3+to+2.5+migration#Struts2.3to2.5migration-StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter)

Comment: The time when question had been asked here there was not Struts version 2.5 released.

Answer (score 0):

This will occur because the correct version of the `struts2-core.jar` is not on the lib path. Please check your **lib** directory and ensure that you have the right version of `struts2-core.jar`.

If you have the jar in your **lib** folder, then you will need to ensure that you are including the correct project library when you deploy your code to your application container. If the Struts 2 Project Library files are not included when you deploy, this error will also occur.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your struts2 library include in you deploy project. Add your struts2 library under WEB-INF file. Then add that to your build path.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. Everybody was suggesting that my **jar version was wrong** but the **problem was different**.

I was adding the required jar in project, but that was not working.

So removed the jar from project and added those jar in my **TOMCAT** server lib folder and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Struts 2.5 the StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter has been moved to the org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter package (without the "ng" in the package).

Answer (score 0):

**Another solution, if the rest of answers doesn't work for you**

If you put the right package path (without .ng..) and you still get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
```

I had the same problem but none of this solutions works, because I got the same error using the right path but the reason was *how the class loader load the classes*.

***The solution is to set in the WAS "Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last)"***

To do this:

> - Click on WebSphere enterprise applications.
> - Choose your enterprise application
> - Click on Manage Modules.
> - Click on your module.
> - "Select Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent 
>     last)" from the Class loader order drop 
>     down list.
> - Click on OK.
> - Click on Save.
> - restart the websphere server (or virtual server in my case).

If this work for you then the best way of doing this is setting an deployment.xml in the EAR project, so in futures deployment this is setted automated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<appdeployment:Deployment 
        xmi:version="2.0" 
        xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" 
        xmlns:appdeployment=" 
http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/schemas/5.0/appdeployment.xmi"> 

        <deployedObject xmi:type="appdeployment:ApplicationDeployment" 
startingWeight="10"> 

                <modules 
                        xmi:type="appdeployment:WebModuleDeployment" 
                        startingWeight="10000" 
                        uri="<your war name>" 
                        classloaderMode="PARENT_LAST" /> 
                <classloader mode="PARENT_LAST" /> 
        </deployedObject> 
</appdeployment:Deployment>
```

***I found out the solution here:*** 
 [Solution - class loader configuration in WAS](http://struts.1045723.n5.nabble.com/Running-Struts-2-Project-in-WebSphere-Application-Serve-7-0-0-19-tp5612359p5715570.html)

Answer (score 0):

the solution is in pom.xml;

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <finalName>struts-2.3-hello-world-example</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>web\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

i can see this, in this video; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4IhM4GBhF8

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i was using 2.3.3 with "org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter" following the original struts guide in the oficial page, i just changed my version to 2.5 and it worked