# Docker container running one computer and not another

Tags: java, docker, struts2, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to deploy a WebSphere Liberty Application via Docker. I'm also using Apache Struts for the UI. When deploying on my local machine I have no problems, but when put on seemingly any other machine, it throws an error saying the struts2 filter cannot be loaded. Classes do not seem to be missing.

**Why would this container work on one machine and not another?**

Stack Trace:

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0321E: The [struts2] filter did not load during start up.

Filter [struts2]: could not be initialized

[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: java.lang.Throwable: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [struts2]: could not be initialized

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:5027)

at [internal classes]

Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [struts2]: could not be initialized

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:163)

... 1 more

Caused by: Unable to create SAX parser - Class: com.icl.saxon.aelfred.SAXParserFactoryImpl

File: SAXParserFactoryImpl.java

Method: newSAXParser

Line: 34 - com/icl/saxon/aelfred/SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:34:-1

at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:835)

at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:131)

at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:100)

at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reload(DefaultConfiguration.java:130)

at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:52)

at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:395)

at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:452)

at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:201)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:149)

... 1 more

Caused by: Unable to create SAX parser - Class: com.icl.saxon.aelfred.SAXParserFactoryImpl

File: SAXParserFactoryImpl.java

Method: newSAXParser

Line: 34 - com/icl/saxon/aelfred/SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:34:-1

at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:111)

at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:830)

... 9 more

Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: AElfred parser is non-validating

at com.icl.saxon.aelfred.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:34)

at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:109)

... 10 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256939/severe-exception-starting-filter-struts2-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: AElfred parser is non-validating

The struts2 requires to have a validating parser. Since this parser is non-validating it should be removed from the classpath.

The affected parser could be found in `saxon.jar`.

Comment: That did the trick! Updated the JAR with a more recent version and my problem was solved. Thank you so much!

Comment: Update: This did work, but I also found that as I updated the JAR to a newer version I also had to add some other jars. Specifically, saxon-dom-8.jar and jaxp-api-1.4.2.jar. Before adding these I got errors regarding an Illegal Argument Exception. YMMV on the versions, but you need those jars to handle dom components

Comment: Update: My initial thoughts were wrong. Updating the parser worked briefly, but later broke. I answered the question with my findings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Roman I was able to diagnose this problem more correctly as a saxon XML parser issue. I tried just replacing my JAR and this actually worked for a few tests but later broke.

This forum post ultimately solved the problem: http://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/031xc9jye7/i-cant-use-saxon-xml-parser-in-my-web-app-please-help

My web server (WebSphere Liberty) was trying to use Saxon as the XML parser, however Saxon is non-validating and thus this was failing, particularly in Docker where I was trying this.

**To fix this I had to remove the file `javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory` from the JAR and then the server ran correctly.**